# SDI 12 interface

Tags: serial, driver, interface

I have a sensor that use SDI-12 communication. I want to connect it to a a µC. I'm looking for something like RS232 <-> SDI-12. Or USB <-> SDI-12 the only schematics I've found use buffer.

Do you have an idea about the interface / driver?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide links to the sensor or SD-12 comms description. Maybe read the links to see if it helps. If the linked data helps then that's good. If the linked data is confusing you then ask a question that relates to that confusion. [Link that may answer your doubts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwj2ypqAjO7ZAhUCQMAKHdS9AY4QFghIMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fs.campbellsci.com%2Fdocuments%2Fsp%2Fmanuals%2Fsentek_v3_4.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1NpiLR4jiNJ4jeLIpmjpLd)

Comment: Have you considered also formally accepting the best answer to questions you have previously raised. You can upvote good answer too. This is the currency around here and although it's nice to say "thank you", it's better to "pay the man".

Comment: Thank you Andy Aka, but I was looking for an integrated circuit which could do the job. I should extract the data from a sensor (That i can't change) and give the signal to a µC, on only one board.
About the upvote, sorry I didn't know why it wasn't count. Thanks for remind me.